# Avoid Regex catastrophic backtracking in "dateparser" Python package

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to optimize dateparser (https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) logic. I've copied the source and here I have a Regex like:

```
(
    (
        (?P<digits>\d+)
        |
        ## Grab any digits
        (?P<digits_modifier>{digits_modifier})
        {time}
        |
        (?P<days>{days})
        |
        (?P<months>{months})
        |
        ## Delimiters, ie Tuesday[,] July 18 or 6[/]17[/]2008
        ## as well as whitespace
        (?P<delimiters>{delimiters})
        |
        ## These tokens could be in phrases that dateutil does not yet recognize
        ## Some are US Centric
        (?P<extra_tokens>{extra_tokens})

    ){{3,}}
)
```

I don't want to copy + paster {days}, {months} ... substituted fragments here because they are too verbose,
but here are the sources:
the code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/a8KVbjGb
the resulted Regex: https://www.codepile.net/pile/NnDJ4rzm

The Regex successfully searches for dates in text like

```
Beginning on February 1, 1998, and\ncontinuing until July 18, 2002,
```

But sometimes the regex is too slow. Especially when dealing with tables in plain text like this:

```
710                5,208             1,577             2,274             
3,302             15,638           5,603            - 
32,584           166,848
```

I guess there is a *catastrophic backtracking* issue (it doesn't happen if I remove "(?P\d+)" Regex part, but then I ruin my parsing logic) But I don't know how to avoid it here.

What I have tried:

1) simplifying and tuning some simple sub-patterns:

```
\d+ -> \d\d* or \d+ -> \d{1,8}
ACDT|ACST|ACT|ACWDT|ACWST -> AC(DT|ST|T|WDT|WST)
```

All that I've got is performance improvement like 44s to 42.5s.

2) I've tried to *break* the source text by separators like '  ', '|', '['

```
re.split(r'\|. |; |\s\s', text)
```

and then processing the resulted text chunks. But then I've failed to pass unit tests for text like

```
" Beginning on February 1,    1998"
```

Comment: You have a lot of alternations. A lof of them are very similar, and start with the patterns that can match the same text - that is bad practice. You should make sure the alternatives do not start with such patterns. E.g. `\d+st|\d+th|\d+rd` => `\d+(?:st|th|rd)`. `(?P<time_periods>a\.m\.|am|p\.m\.|pm)?` => `(?P<time_periods>[ap](?:\.m\.|m))?`. And so on. I can't debug it as for PCRE, it is reported as [too large](https://regex101.com/r/wVGTyu/1).

Comment: This makes sense. But I've tried
 bracketing like ACDT|ACST|ACT|ACWDT|ACWST => AC(DT|ST|T|WDT|WST) and got only ~ 2% increase in processing speed.